# Xcode/LLDB being needlessly terse

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

For a while now, I've been having an issue where I'll cause an assertion to fail in some library code somewhere and Xcode is not forthcoming about what I did.
Normally when this happens (for example when you delete tableview rows but don't remove them from the data source), you get an error like this in the log:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[SomeClass someMethodName:], /Some/Source/Path/File.m:###
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'SomeException', reason: 'A helpfully descriptive reason for the crash'
```

Lately, I've been getting the first line, but no second line.  It's hard for me to debug on a vague sense of I-did-something-wrong-to-`SomeClass`.  From this point, if I hit continue in the debugger, it just hits the same line (that one we all know in `main.m`) and changes the stop reason from `SIGABRT` to `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_i386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`.

What did I change to discourage Xcode from being helpful and how do I turn helpfulness back on?

**Update 2014/11/17**:

When I crash an app by putting the wrong thing in an auto layout visual format string, I get no printout at all.  It should say something about the view not being found some other error with the string, but it just pauses in the debugger with the same behavior as above.  I can't remember whether that error is preceded by an assertion, but if it is then neither is getting printed in this case.

Comment: The sequence is like this: (1) assertion fails, (2) exception is thrown, (3) exception unwinding runs, (4) uncaught exception is logged, (5) process terminates. It sounds like something during 2-4 is itself failing and killing the process.

Answer (score 0):

Those error messages are not produced by Xcode.  The first comes when an exception is raised in a Foundation method, and the second is output by the uncaught exception handler in Foundation.  They are both written to stdout, which is why you see them in the Debugger console window.  Note you won't see either message in Xcode when you attach to a process - then the output will go to the Console.app log.

I'm not sure why you aren't getting the second line, maybe something is overriding the default uncaught exception handler?

Anyway, the easiest way to figure out what is happening when an exception is being thrown is to turn on the ObjC exception breakpoint.  You can do this in Xcode in the Add Breakpoint popup, or in lldb with:

```
(lldb) break set -E objc
```

then when you hit this breakpoint do:

```
(lldb) po $arg1
```

The first argument is the exception object being thrown, and the `po` will print the reason field of the exception.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. OP understands what the exceptions are and how to use them, but wants to know why his usual tool for viewing them -- Xcode -- is not presenting all the information that it should.

Comment: Just to add information to this discussion, I have tried it with the exception breakpoint enabled and disabled in Xcode with no change from either state.

Comment: To Josh...  Not sure why you say that.  The point is this information is NOT being generated by Xcode.  You'd get the same information by looking in the Console.log (or device console) if the app raised an uncaught exception when launched outside the debugger.  That you know not to look to Xcode for the answer to why you aren't seeing this info - since Xcode wasn't responsible for producing it - seemed a useful data point.

Comment: Dan, when the exception breakpoint was turned on, did you hit the breakpoint or not?  If you did hit it, did "po $arg1" give you a reasonable description of the exception.  If so, something's going wrong in the catching of the exception - maybe somebody else catching the exception and calling abort before it gets to the Foundation handler - which is what prints the second message?

Comment: You might try setting a breakpoint on "abort" and see who is calling it.  That will tell you whether this got caught by the Foundation uncaught exception handler or not.  BTW, if you're on 10.10, abort calls "pthread_kill" so you will stop with a SIGABRT on the thread that called abort.  On earlier systems abort just called "kill" so the main thread would stop with the SIGABRT, and you'd have to hunt around for the thread that called abort...